# Git workflow: how to save and share changes in a clean way

Tags: git

This is a question about a best practice. It's probably simple but I'm still fairly new with Git, and I'd like to get good habits for things I do frequently.

The situation is the following. I have two computers CompA and CompB, and a remote repository (on Bitbucket). Let's say I work on a unique branch.

I need to make a big change on a file. I start from Computer A, but I do not have time to finish, and will need to carry on my work on Computer B. I'd like to make available to Computer B the changes already made on Computer A.

I usually do it by committing the changes as they are, pushing to remote repo, then pulling them to Computer B. However, this creates a commit which is not a full self-sufficient set of changes.

If possible I would like to have only one commit with the final set of changes. At least in the remote repo, if possible, also in the local repos of computers A and B.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Should this go to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big changes probably are best made on a separate branch, as it is very easy to create one in Git. Commit as much as you want, push the branch to BitBucket, pull it on computer B... You can use `git rebase --interactive` to squash commits together before merging them to the master branch.

```
[master] $ git checkout -b fixXYZ
[fixXYZ] $ hack hack hack
[fixXYZ] $ git commit -m "Fixed some part"
[fixXYZ] $ hack hack
[fixXYZ] $ git commit -m "Fixed another part"
[fixXYZ] $ git push -u origin fixXYZ
```

Later, anytime *before* merging to master:

```
[master] $ git checkout fixsomething
[fixXYZ] $ git rebase -i master
```

(Although it is not necessary to squash everything into a single commit – sometimes it is easier to read a log of several smaller commits.)

Comment: Thanks! What if not's big enough to warrant a whole branch? By big I meant something long enough that I may have to switch computers in the middle.

Comment: @Peutch: Branches in Git are very [cheap](http://git-scm.com/about/branching-and-merging) to create and use, there's no real reason to avoid them. If you do not know how long will something take, you can create a branch anytime, even just before leaving to another PC, too -- it is not necessary to do it at the very beginning.